# List coordinates of single colored contiguous areas of image

Tags: image-processing, colors, coordinates, area, contiguous

I am looking for an implementation of an algorithm that takes an image file - eg png, a colour as inputs and outputs a list of coordinates of contiguous regions in the image.

One coordinate would match a region's pixel that is the same colour as defined in the input.

I just don't want to reinvent the wheel if someone has already solved this problem. I have a hunch it has been resolved by someone already. I have just failed to find it.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need `cv::inRange()` and `cv::connectedComponents()`, maybe `cv::findContours()`

Please take a course on *image processing*. You know the term already. Questions like this are answered by formal education.